# New environment or Base environment is not showing any packages in "Not installed"

Tags: keras, anaconda, conda

[image: This is the Anaconda Navigator menu image attached via link as I could not post the image]

I got errors of importing and I want to add packages of `keras`, `opencv` and `tensorflow` in Anaconda Navigator. Earlier it was showing the packages that are not installed in the "not installed" tab and I could just add any packages.
Now it is not showing any packages in the "not installed" menu. How can I add the above packages?

I tried to use `conda install <package>`. It successfully installs the package but the code still give error for the same.

How to resolve the "Not installed" menu problem so I can add packages again?

Comment: _Earlier it was showing the packages that are not installed in the "not installed" tab and I could just add any packages. Now it is not showing any packages in the "not installed" menu._ What happens if you try to search for them? _I tried to use conda install . It successfully installs the package but the code still give error for the same._ That sounds like a separate issue, it's best to focus on a single one for now.

Comment: Maybe you installed on different environment and not activated that environment. Can you confirm the environment activation with conda activate environment_name and that with pip list. This could be the reason.

Comment: It works now. Maybe the issue was of the different versions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the procedure and check if still it is not working. Also, keep your python to 3.7 unless you know which version you need.

The command procedure from scratch

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7

conda activate myenv

pip install tensorflow
pip install Keras
pip install opencv-python
```

and than

```
pip list
```

you will see installed packages. Let me know if this doesn't work. If this works, let me know.

Comment: Works. Guess it was issue of the difference of versions. Thank you.